# Ubuntu displaying GDM but no login

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

Ubuntu (Wubi, Lucid Lynx) boots and shows the login screen itself with the background and plays the boot sound but a list of users is never displayed. A mouse is on screen and I can move it but, alas, it does nothing. Dropping to a virtual term with CTRL+Alt+F# drops me to a cursor but I can't actually input anything. I can't boot into single-user with GRUB since it's Wubi and it never specifies a boot kernel directly in GRUB's initial menu.lst (only in files that it then reads from).

Other details that may be helpful:

- Single monitor
- Same video card that's been working for months
- No new hardware

Edit:
  I ssh'd in since it evidently booted up the sshd which is handy. dpkg-reconfigure gdm didn't do anything helpful. I do, however, get a "no seat-id found" when manually running it.

Comment: Can you post your xorg.conf?

Comment: You can boot into recovery mode unless you disabled recovery options in your /etc/defaults/grub file.  If the timeout is too short, hold SHIFT immediately after you select `Ubuntu` from the Windows Boot Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, don't hate me for this (and maybe I'll get about 25 downvotes, but well.. it happens.). Wubi is not capable of normal usage. It's just for a showoff, like you install it on a PC.. look the cube is spinning and.. and ..it's spinning. And with that you convinced the user to replace his OS (and make his life a little bit more harder. :D)

So basically you should simply just resize your main partition of Windows with the free in-built partition manager or with a commercial one like: Acronis Disk director. Then install Ubuntu to the new partition.

Answer (score 0):

Would love to I've just been lazy about doing it and I don't need the Windows partition anymore. However, I doubt the issue would go away just by blowing away Windows. As far as not being for normal usage I've been using it "normally" for 2 years without issue so it's not like it's running some half-cocked version of Ubuntu.